# how to hide a specific child tag using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out how i could hide a specific element within another. example:

```
  <form  name='demo_form'>
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
  </select>
  <input id="submit1" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

so say I want to hide just the Select tag and leave the rest.

I know if i did

```
$(demo_form.elements).hide();
```

would hide the whole thing, and leave just the First Last name text, but really isn't useful to me for this.

I tried

```
$(demo_form.select).hide();
$("demo_form > select").hide();
```

but i got nothing from that.

I know i could do

```
$("form > select").hide();
$("#submit1").click(function() {
         event.preventDefault();
         $("form > select").show();
})
```

(the show was something i was toying around with, thinking maybe i want the extra info to be shown after user makes a submission)

the only problem with what i know i can do is that it'll grab all forms and all selects, I want to be able to grab a particular form and grab it's respective selects, or any tags that i want without having to always give those child tags an id.

any suggestions would be great! thanks.

Comment: on what instance do you want to hide the select?

Comment: yes, it is possible, but it depends on a number of things. When do you want it hidden? are there always 1 select? if there are more selects, do you want them all hidden?

Comment: well at this point i'm just trying to figure out how to do it, didn't occur to me the parameters around it. Lets say for now, i don't think i need it, but i don't want to remove it from the html doc, just hide it for the time being. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Umeed hide it on load?

Comment: ah yes hide it on load, however Mikey and jeffdill just answered it. thanks. but you and Cory brought up good questions which I'm going to try and figure out now that there's a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you, if you're wanting to base your selection based off of the `name` attribute:

```
$("form[name='demo_form'] > select").hide();
```

This will hide only the `select` elements that are direct children of a `form` with a `name` attribute of "demo_form".

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for thank you! i had no idea we could grab an element using [ ]. Mikey's solution is quick and clean which will come handy later, but this is exactly what i needed thank you Jeff!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is just:

```
$('select[name=cars]').hide();
```

Personally, I like to give my inputs a `name` and `id` of the same value:

```
<select id="cars" name="cars"> ... </select>
```

The `id` attribute is used for a faster retrieval by jQuery, So, instead of the above, it would be:

```
$('#cars').hide();`
```

The `name` attribute is used for sending data when you submit the form. (Though, there are ways to send data without using the `name` attribute.)

Comment: wow i had no idea you could do it that way lol this is awesome clean and quick. thanks!

Comment: oooh interesting. would it be simpler to use both an `ID` and `NAME` if I wanted to send data when submitting the form? or are the other ways you're talking about would combine the two to make it simpler?

Comment: It's simpler to just use `id` and `name`. The other ways require more work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's selector `context` to limit your selectors to a specific element. For example, to hide all `select` elements within your form:

```
$('select', 'form[name="demo_form"]').hide();
```

Passing an element as a 2nd argument to `$()` will restrict the search for the selector to the element. The above will effect all `select` tags within the `form[name='demo_form']` element.